# How to optimize intent usage in service with swich-case constraction

Tags: java, android, refactoring, android-service

I'm truying to optimize my service code with switch-case construction to avoid multiple if-else clauses, that make the code less readable.

So, to use switch-case we need a condition (I mean "switch(){//some login}.

Which condition should I use with intent object to simplify this code?

```
  @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (intent == null) {
                return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            }
            if (intent.hasExtra(ChatManager.WS_CONNECT)) {
                ChatManager.getInstance().start(chatCallbackConnect, false);
            } else if (intent.hasExtra(ChatManager.CHAT_CONNECT)) {
                try {
                    String roomId = intent.getStringExtra(ChatManager.INTENT_EXTRA_ROOM_ID);
                    String roomIdRoomId = intent.getStringExtra(ChatManager.INTENT_EXTRA_ROOM_ID_ROOM_ID);
                    ChatManager.getInstance().getMessage(roomId, roomIdRoomId, chatCallbackMessage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log("ChatService. Exception: " + e);
                }
            } else if (intent.hasExtra(ChatManager.MSG_SEND)) {
                String message = intent.getStringExtra(ChatManager.MSG_SEND);
                ChatManager.getInstance().sendMessage("topic/" + ChatManager.getInstance().getTopicId(), message);
            } else if (intent.hasExtra(ChatManager.ADD_USER)) {
                String user = intent.getStringExtra(ChatManager.ADD_USER);
                ChatManager.getInstance().addUser(user, chatCallbackAddUser);
            } else if (intent.hasExtra(ChatManager.CREATE_GROUP)) {
                String group = intent.getStringExtra(ChatManager.CREATE_GROUP);
                ChatManager.getInstance().createGroup(group, chatCallbackCreateGroup);
            } else if (intent.hasExtra(ChatManager.CHAT_DISCONNECT)) {
                ChatManager.getInstance().disconnect();
                stopSelf();
            }
```

Comment: (Readability is a noble pursuit, indeed. (Commenting your code helps it - start with a doc comment (inherit?) for `onStartCommand()`.) I don't see how to use `switch` with `Intent`'s extras.)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use a function which returns integer values. Like it return 1 if it has Chat.Ws and 2 if it has Chat.xy etc. Now you can put switch as under.

Then:-
switch(value) {
 case 1: //do this
break;
//...........
default: // do that

But again you have to use if else there for getting values.

Comment: The method name is "getExtras()" and it returns Bundle so it will not help me to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making Intent polymorphic One subclass per case. Then each Intent subclass can just do what is necessary.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null) {
            return super.onStartCommand(null, flags, startId);
        }
        intent.doWhatIsNecessary(...);
```